# How to see what is exactly signed while sending request from soapui

Tags: soapui, sign

I have a test project in soap ui and eqivalent application in c# to comunicate with web service.
I find a problem with signing part of my soap message: the digestvalue created by soapui is different then digestvalue created in c# application. I cant find what is reason to this differences.
i want to compare my part of envelope to sign with part prepared to sign by soapui
(after canonalization). Is any way to see what exactly is signed in SoapUI ?

Answer (score 0):

In SoapUI you can see logs containing some informations like code response, header requestion and even Soap Envelope. 
You can check Http Log in the Bottom.

Comment: the canonical version of signed xml isn't displayed in log, header etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I found where was a problem. SoapUi doesn't remove whitespaces then it is very important to correctly format signed Xml part (try Alt-F).
In c# for xmlDocument I try to change values of PreserveWhitespaces and after that I get correct digest value.